# Buffer Pool in SQL Server FileStream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, filestream

One of the best feature of `FileStream` is : [The SQL Server buffer pool is not used; therefore, this memory is available for query processing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server)

I have encountered an issue that If I create a stored procedure for return file from my `FileStream` table, Will The SQL Server buffer pool be used? Is it possible to take advantage of benefits of `FileStream` with `T-SQL` and SPs?

Thanks

Comment: Have you encountered the issue that it *is* using that memory? Your question isn't really clear.